# Google Finance API to retrieve currency exchange rates

Tags: google-finance-api

Now that Yahoo Finance API is dead, is there any way to retrieve currency exchange rates via Google Finance API (which, afaik, is also not really supported)?

I would like to get, for example, EURUSD=X from [Google Finance](https://finance.google.com/finance?q=EURUSD) which will now show 1.1600 - this number is the only thing I need. So the output to be in JSON or CSV format, anything parse-able.

If yes, is there an option to request multiple currencies?